# sphinx documentation not getting docstrings/modules

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx, autodoc, code-documentation

Hej! :)

I want to create a documentation of my django project and using sphinx. I wrote docstring to every function and class which I want to be integrated automatically.

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/sphinx-for-django-documentation-2454e924b3bc/) and everything run. My documentation won't give me the docstring information but `myProject.app.views module` as an output (for every file in my project) but no information whats in the file.

```
# file system

biodata
   - biodata 
        - settings.py
   - docs
   - stakeholders
        - templates
            - search_tables_institutions.html
        - views.py
        - ...
   - plants 
        - templates
        - views.py
   - manage.py
   - ...
```

```
# stakeholders.views.py

@login_required
def search_institution(request):

    """
    View for institutions

    login for view between landing page and view required.
    Searches in all available institutions.

    One can filter after multiple filter options. Singular and combined.
    e.g. in Germany with name DBFZ. Or e.g. everything in Saxony.

    :param request: object to pass the state. When page/url is requested by user
    :return: rendered request results
    :rtype: HttpResponse
    """

    institutions = Institution.objects.all()

    myFilter = InstitutionFilter(request.GET, queryset=institutions)
    institutions = myFilter.qs

    context = {"institutions": institutions, "myFilter": myFilter}

    return render(request, 'stakeholders/search_table_institutions.html', context)
```

I navigate to /docs/ and run the command `sphinx-quickstart` which creates all necessary files as in the sphinx documentation. I edit the conf.py and index.rst

```
# conf.py
import os
import sys
import django
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'biodata.settings'
django.setup()


extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc','sphinx.ext.napoleon']
```

My app.rst looks like that:

```
biodata.stakeholders package

============================

Subpackages
-----------

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4

   biodata.stakeholders.migrations
   biodata.stakeholders.templatetags


Submodules
---------
biodata.stakeholders.views module

----------------------------------

.. automodule:: biodata.stakeholders.views
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

```
# index.rst

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:


.. automodule:: Run
       :members:

Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

The commands I'm using are:
`sphinx-apidoc -o . ..` and `make html`

I do get .rst files for each of my files, they are just pretty much empty.
When running `make html` the following message appeared.

```
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'stakeholders.admin' from module 'biodata'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'biodata.stakeholders'
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or missing?

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Missing `pip install biodata`?

Comment: Or missing `sys.path` entry in conf.py? See first note here: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html.

Comment: biodata is my project name.
I will add my conf.py

Comment: I think you need `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))`, so that the directory above the top-level `biodata` package is in `sys.path`.

Comment: I already tried this. Then it won't find biodata.settings

The problem seems to be to get from the settings up into the different apps/files. It does find all files in all apps though. It just won't get the methods and classes and their docstrings.

I'm using `sphinx-quickstart`, `sphinx-apidoc -o . ..`, `make html` as commands.

Comment: Your project structure is not clear to me. You have a `biodata` directory that contains a `biodata` subdirectory. Which of these directories corresponds to the top-level `biodata` **package**?

Comment: the first biodata directory is my django project. The subdirectory is generated by django and contains the settings.py, general urls.py, asgi.py and wsgi.py.
The first level is the general package I want the documentation for.

Comment: whats so strange to me is the fact that I do get the names of all files but not the docstrings within them.

Comment: I think you need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I edited my question. 
Is it now clearer?

Comment: If `biodata.stakeholders.views` is a correct fully qualified module name, then you need `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))` in conf.py, as I have already said.